# Not changing the properties for fields via control array

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, controls

I have the WinForm, there I have a lot of controls, and on certain moments I need to change the properties for some of them.. so, I create the **Control array** and determines what should be changed

```
controls = new Control[] {loadFromFile_btn, logout_btn, postBtn, waitFrom_tb, waitTo_tb, messageTB, recurs_check};
ChangeStatus.activStatus(controls);
```

Then in my class **ChangeStatus** make changes to all of these elements are in an array

```
public static void activStatus(Control[] controlObj)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < controlObj.Count() - 1; i++)
        {
            controlObj[i].BeginInvoke((Action)delegate
            {
                if (controlObj[i] is TextBox || controlObj[i] is CheckBox || controlObj[i] is Panel)
                    controlObj[i].Enabled = true;
                else
                {
                    controlObj[i].BackColor = Color.DarkGray;
                    controlObj[i].Enabled = true;
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

But I have a problem... the change applies only to the last element in the array. Help me please..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because of the [closure](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx).Try storing `i` in a local variable and use it in your anonymous method

```
 for (int i = 0; i < controlObj.Count() - 1; i++)
    {
        int j = i;
        controlObj[i].BeginInvoke((Action)delegate
        {
            if (controlObj[j] is TextBox || controlObj[j] is CheckBox || controlObj[j] is Panel)
                controlObj[j].Enabled = true;
            else
            {
                controlObj[j].BackColor = Color.DarkGray;
                controlObj[j].Enabled = true;
            }
        });
    }
```